# Help with inequality of rank of sum, using the rank of the product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

I am getting a hard time while trying to prove the following inequality: If $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices, then

$rank{(A + B)} \leq rank{(A)} + rank{(B)} - rank{(AB)}.$

I've tried a lot, but I can't insert the rank of $AB$ in the inequality (the others factors appears easily). I will appreciate any help.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $AB=BA$, you can find a proof here: [Proving $\text{rank}(A+B) \leq \text{rank}(A) + \text{rank}(B) - \text{rank}(AB)$ when $A,B$ commute](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441339/proving-textrankab-leq-textranka-textrankb-textrankab?rq=1)

A counterexample for the non-commutative case is the following. Consider the matrices

$$ A=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array} \right)\quad \text{and} \quad
%
B=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right).
$$
Then, $$ A+B=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right)\quad \text{and} \quad
%
AB=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array} \right).
$$
Lastly, $$rank(A+B)=2>1=1+1-1 = rank(A)+rank(B)-rank(AB). $$